# How did the word Yetzer begot it's meaning of inclination?

Tags: words, commentaries, evil-inclination, thought

Looking for the connection of Yetzer and the translation as inclanation, I was surprised that almost every Hebrew word derived from the same root had to do with creating.

So how did a word (from a root with a common denominator of creating) begot the meaning of inclination?

Information I found based on etymology:

The word yetzer יצר is related to the verb yatzar יצר which means something like 'to create, fashion, produce or form'.

But within the Etymological Dictionary of Biblical Hebrew by S.R.Hirsch I found a nice reference to the Aramaic word yitzra יצרא which according to Hirsch means inclination.

But other translations of what seems to be the same word (איצרא) in phrases like yitzra d'ervah and yitzra d'avodah zarah translate it as tempter, urge, intent, drive.

Are there any commentaries that show the connection?

Comment: כי יצר לב האדם רע מנעוריו

Comment: @Double AA: A inclination is often being described as a feeling to do something, a predisposition, a natural inclination or tendency to think, act, or proceed in a particular way, or the fact that someone prefer or is more likely to do a particular thing. So the connection to the verse you gave is logical and also well known, but how is this connected to the root which seems to revolve around creating?

Comment: Nachman teaches about the power of imagination. Could I interpret the word yotzer as 'shaping imagination' like a artist imagines something and then creates it, and yetzer as a force of imagination, because both seem to be about actualizing/realising/creating what the mind produces in its imagination. Is this understanding correct?

Comment: I think that Avot D'Rav Natan explains this on some level. But, before I delve further, are you satisfied with @DoubleAA's comment, above, which, perhaps should become an answer?

Comment: @DanF I'm not satisfied because the quote of Bereshit 8:21 should be understand in combination with 6:5 which reads it's the Yetzer machshevot of his heart which is ra, which could be translated as 'the inclination of the thoughts' but also in many other ways like for example 'the 'imagination of the thoughts'. So to think a Yetzer is just an inclination seems not broad enough to represent the full meaning of what a Yetzer is. But I could ve wrong. Secondly the Yetzer seems to be the drive behind the influencenses of the heart, mind, actions which lead to doing good or bad, not only a incl.

Comment: Yetzer means "creation". So, here's a thought (no pun intended.) The heart is the center of emotions and thoughts. The inclination to do good or bad is created in the heart. Thus, the heart creates these good or bad thoughts.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to define yetzer](http://judaism.stackexchange.com/questions/64625/how-to-define-yetzer)

Comment: @DanF I agree, but what about our mind? Would you say it's being influenced by the heart to think wrong?

Comment: @Levi This is the difference between science and philosophy. Often, they overlap. I believe that much of Jewish philosophy attributes the center of emotions and thought in the heart rather than the brain.

Comment: @DanF If the Yetzer is in or from the heart, and we take the heart as the Seat of emotions and thoughts, it seems a Yetzer is the force or drive behind these thoughts and emotions... at least these are my first thoughts. But on the other hand the Tenach never talks about the brain (Moach) but rather about the body and inner man in terms of soul and heart etc. On the other hand there's this teaching about placing our Moach first.. pure intellect above the emotions (and subjective).. how does the Yetzarim fit into this all?

Comment: @Levi last question is interesting. I'll see if I can gather some areas to read up on this concept. I'm quite certain a number of chachamim as well as contemporary writings have discussed this area.

Comment: @DanF thank you, P.s. would you say that the attributes or faculties of the mind (such as reason, imagination, will, perception, intuition, feelings, thoughts etc.) were connected to or figuratively spoken of as comming from the heart (lev), ruach and even nefesh in the Tenach instead of refering to the brain? I'm looking forward to your answers.

Comment: @DanF if you have time I'm looking forward to see what you found

Comment: Thanks for the reminder. It's been about a year since looking at this. No commitments, but B"N, I'll re-explore this.