# Akrasia and the Yetzer Harah

Tags: commentaries, evil-inclination, hermeneutics

I asked many questions about the Yetzarim before trying to figure out the concept, the meaning and the way it works looking at myself and different cognitive studies.

Recently I found a concept called [Akrasia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Akrasia) (comming from Greek philosophers such as Socrates and Aristotle) which came quite close to certain of my own thoughts. Is the concept of Akrasia comparable to the Jewish view of the Yetzer Hara?

Comment: I think that to speak about yetsarim is a choice to think through externalisation.  This is not an objectivable reality

Comment: Perhaps this question should be embedded in [this one](http://judaism.stackexchange.com/q/64625/3)? A very good answer to either would answer both.

Answer (score 1):

This seems more like the idea that a person does not sin unless a wind of folly (so it against his judgement when he is in a regular state) goes into him

[Sotah 3a](http://halakhah.com/sotah/sotah_3.html)

> Resh Lakish said: A person does not commit a transgression unless a spirit of folly [shetuth] enters into him

The yetser harah is the **will**, to do forbidden things (for example the will to have relations with a woman that is forbidden to you), it is not "lack of self-control or the state of acting against one's better judgement" it is the **will** to do something that is against one's better judgement
The will is not forbidden, but the act is forbidden
it seems that "**[Akrasia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Akrasia)**" is regarding the act not the will

Comment: Related http://judaism.stackexchange.com/a/68612/5120

Comment: I agree with you. Yetser is instinct,  very simple translation